# Investigating 2D Oscillating motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring, home-experiment

I once did an experiment into Simple Harmonic motion of a mass oscillating in 1D on a spring. I wanted to extend this into two dimensions. I can see how varying the starting offset and also ratio of spring constants would vary my results. However, I don't know how I would accurately set it up, and also therefore what suitable apparatus would be. Any ideas of equipment to MEASURE and to USE.

Crucially, I wanted to give a starting push to the mass in a direction, with it already being offset, for example to create a circle, byt getting x=cos(t) and y = sin(t). How would i do this in an accurate way that i could measure?

Answer (score 0):

So you want a system of two springs presumably oriented perpendicular to each other, a mass attached to both of them with some initial offset, and for it to move in a circle once you let go. Is that correct?

I have good news and bad news. Let's start with the good news.

When the mass is initially offset along the axis of a spring, an ideal system will, as you've seen in the 1D problem, oscillate according to a wave equation:

$$x(t)=A\cos(\omega t)$$

Where $x$ is the position of the mass at time $t$, $A$ is the initial offset, and $\omega$ is the angular frequency of the oscillations. Note that I have been very specific with that equation; there is no $+\phi$ offset term nor is it a sine wave.

In your question, you correctly anticipated that the spring constants can affect the outcome. Little did you know that this is your saving grace because the angular frequency is:

$$\omega=2\pi\sqrt{k\over m}$$
That is, the angular frequency depends on the spring constant and the mass (which, for all intents and purposes of this setup, is fixed). Now, if we extend this to 2D, we can idealize the situation and keep the perpendicular axes separate. That is, we will have a spring along the x- and y-axes. The mass will be initially offset along each axis by $A$ for the x-axis and $B$ for the y-axis. Thus, we have:
$$x(t)=A\cos(\omega_x t)$$
$$y(t)=B\cos(\omega_y t)$$
If we choose the spring constants just right, the angular frequencies in both directions will be only slightly off and, after enough cycles have passed, the mass will appear to move in a perfect circle. This is because the two waves will go just a bit more out of phase each cycle until it resembles a sine and cosine wave oscillating together.

"But," you say, "I want to somehow have the same spring constants for both and still have it move in a circle". This is where the bad news comes in. If all you do is displace the mass from the rest position, let it go and watch, then you can't make that happen. Take a look back at the equations and note the cosine function. At the start, when you let go of the mass, that's your $t=0$ and that moment defines what the amplitude of your wave is. If you don't offset the mass along a given axis, it won't oscillate in that direction. However, if you offset it in both directions, it will oscillate along a straight line because both functions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are cosine functions with equal angular frequencies.

That all said, there is a way to get your circular motion. Instead of starting with an offset, you could, as you suggested, give a kick along one axis and in addition to an offset along the other. If done right, you would get circular motion.

Now, as for the types of experiments you can do with this. There's not a lot of options. I'll tell you this now, you have very little to gain from extending !D springs to 2D and there will be a lot of practical difficulties. However, if you're set on doing this and want your students to have to calculate something, what you could do is give them two springs with different spring constants and as them to determine the ratio between the spring constants by analyzing the [Lissajous figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_curve). That's the best that me and my co-worker (we're physics lab technicians) could come up with. Anything else we could think of is either not quantitative, not reliably repeatable, or pointless. And there's nothing to be gained from varying the initial offset; it makes no difference.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you very much for your response. Actually, I'm a student and am undergoing a personal investigation. It turned out that i wanted to use parametric equations which I studied in further maths and the Lissajous Figures, which I was not aware was a formal term, was actually the graphs I was aiming to recreate. However, I don't see how i can recreate them without giving a different offset to the Sine function (clearly now not with an offset in position).  The equations require a delta in one. I presume the offset in position would determine the amplitutude of the oscillations.

Comment: Anyways, your help has made me realise that my personal investigation is not feasable. Do you know of any other interesting, newtonian-mechanics experiments (with the ability to have variation to investigate different properties) that are rooted in mathematics?

Comment: @RetAFVLib That's a fairly broad request. Most Newtonian mechanics fall under that umbrella, but no I don't have any specific things in mind